# Blending two textures together

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

[image: material nodes]
I'm trying to make an island in blender. I went over to textures and made one texture I called sand, and one texture I called dirt.

Now, as I'm blending dirt and sand together, the sand overlaps the dirt (there is much more sand than there is dirt) Anybody know why this is or/ and have a solution to it? It looks kinda like the picture above on the left.

Comment: Using a blend texture should work. If you are in cycles just throw it in a mix shader. Don't know the process for Blender Internal but probably the same kind of thing. Or use a color ramp to blend them. Hope it helps