# blending two textures terrain

Tags: texturing

I am working on a terrain and want to blend two or three textures. Rocky texture for the top of the mountains and then more or a desert texture for the bottom land. Someone asked this similar question sometime back.

[Blending two textures together](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/blending-two-textures-together)

While someone answered it was not really helpful for me. I get around in the nodes editor just enough to be dangerous. I know I need some mix nodes and texture generator but and maybe a Texture coordinator but not sure how to hook everything up. Any Ideas?

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/cycles-material-with-color-based-on-height-and-backside-in-different-colors/67145#67145

Answer (score 0):

Use a **gradient texture** and a **color ramp** to control the mix between two shaders.

The placement of the gradient can be controlled with a mapping node.

[image]

[image]

A variation on the same idea is to use a Separate XYZ node and use only the information on the Z coordinates for the gradient texture and color ramp.

Playing with scale or location will allow you to control the transition between different shaders.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful as it is helping me to understand how the nodes work. Can something like this be done using image textures?